# Oracle Packages, Procedures and Functions Not Respecting Roles

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, security, plsql, role

When you create a package, stored procedure or function in one schema (say, `SCHEMA1`) that accesses objects in another schema (`SCHEMA2`), even when `SCHEMA1` has appropriate permissions to the respective `SCHEMA2` objects, granted through roles, Oracle will complain that the `SCHEMA2` object cannot be found. Even if you are calling a package as `SCHEMA2` that is set to `authid current_user`, it complains. Apparently, to get around this problem, you have to explicitly grant permissions to `SCHEMA1` (e.g., `grant select on schema2.some_object to schema1;`).

I have come against this issue several times, now: It's always something I forget about because it seems so counter-intuitive! Could anyone offer an explanation as to why roles aren't respected by PL/SQL objects?

Answer (score 2):

When you execute PL/SQL in a package/procedure/trigger, Oracle disables roles (this is not the case for anonymous blocks). As a result, you have to grant permissions directly, rather than through roles.

Jonathan Lewis explains this well [here](http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/faq/plsql_privs.html), plus it's covered in the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/authorization.htm#i1007304).

Invoker/definers rights are documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00809).

Comment: +1 for the references, but this doesn't really explain to me the motivation behind this decision. The best I could quickly glean is that roles are just for user maintenance, but that seems an arbitrary constraint. What security concern does disabling roles within PL/SQL solve?

Comment: Oracle has always worked this way. The only people that can say "why?" are the original developers/design team. You will not find such an answer anywhere. I imagine it because of complications arising from pl/sql compiling to bytecode and associated permissions checking overhead.